# How to run all tests of all modules in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-module

I'm working on an app with several modules built by other teams in my company.
Is there a way that we can run the tests in the app and all the imported modules with one command?
We need it for CI.

Comment: Are you separated modules by declaring it on another directories with and each contains `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: I don't think thats possible. Why don't you test your modules when bundeling them for your app? I think we need more information in terms of how you are building your modules and how you are including them in your app.

Comment: It's still under investigation what's the best way to do it.
We have an Android and an iOS project that we want to integrate flutter into. You can only implement one module so we are working on a umbrella module that can import all the other modules. That way we can import only that module and get all the ones imported to that one.
We need it to pas CI, which should include testing all the modules independently and together. That means we want to run the umbrella test folder and all the sub modules test folders.